# Como colocar valor default num input type hidden no angularjs com ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Boa noite,

Tenho um app móvel, estou a submeter um form com uma `input type hidden` mas quero que essa input tenha o valor passado de um outro controller mas não estou a conseguir passar já tentei `ng-init` mas não funciona

**Input**

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="input.estabelecimento">
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('SugerirCorrecao', function($scope, $http, sessionService) {
$scope.BtnSugerirCorrecao= function (input){
    $http.post("https://www.sabeonde.pt/api/api_sugerir_correcao.php?user_report=" + sessionService.get('nome') + "&telefone=" + input.telefone + "&morada=" + input.morada + "&encerrado=" + input.encerrado + "&menu=" + input.menu + "&detalhes=" + input.detalhes + "&estabelecimento=" + input.estabelecimento).success(function (data) {
        alert("A sua sugestão foi enviada com sucesso!");
        $scope.editar_perfil = data;
    }).
    error(function (data) {
        alert("Não foi possivel enviar a sua sugestão!");
    });
}
```

})

**Controller do titulo que quero passar**

```
.controller('TitEstabelecimento', function($scope, $http, $stateParams) {
$http.get("https://www.sabeonde.pt/api/api_tit_estabelecimento.php?slug="+$stateParams.EstabelecimentoSlug).success(function (data) {
    $scope.tit_estabelecimento = data;
});
```

})

Answer (score 2):

Se você quiser fazer a passagem de uma variável de um Controller para outro, eu te aconselho fazer isso através de um Service que acessado pelas duas.

Exemplo:

Primeiro Controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('ngapp').controller('LoginController', function(global){

  this.user = global.info.user || null;
  this.password = null;
});
```

Service:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('ngapp').service('global', function(){

  this.info = {
    user: null
  };
});
```

Segundo Controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('ngapp').controller('MainController', function($rootScope, global, mainService, $state){

  if(global.info.usuer == null){
    $state.go('login');
  }
});
```